# Can I expand the view of a structure in IDAPython?

Tags: ida, idapython

When I define data as a structure with IDAPython, it appears in IDA View in a collapsed view. Out of curiosity, **is it possible to *programmatically* expand the view of the structure?**

For example, if I run `MakeStructEx(0x400000, -1, "IMAGE_DOS_HEADER")`, I see:

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER <5A4Dh, 90h, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0FFFFh, 0, 0B8h, 0, 0, 0, \
                  40h, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0E0h>
```

But I would like to see:

```
dw 5A4D                ; e_magic
dw 90h                 ; e_cblp
dw 3                   ; e_cp
dw 0                   ; e_crlc
... (lines removed) ...
dd 0E0h                ; e_lfanew
```

I am using IDA 6.2.

Answer (score 6):

Put the text cursor somewhere between the `<` and `>` and press **+ on the numeric keypad**.

Comment: Just for completeness : in IDA 6.8 it is Ctrl and +

Comment: I know the keyboard shortcut, but I am looking for a programmatic solution. For example, something I can control with IDAPython

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I don't have IDA 6.2, but if this version supports IDAPython and corresponding APIs you can try to do the following:

```
import idc
idc.Jump(address)
idc.ProcessUiAction("UnHide", 0)
```

This will move the cursor to the "address" ea and replay user action associated with "UnHide" string, which is <kbd>Ctrl+Numpad+</kbd>, which does what you requested in IDA 6.8. I think that it should work in IDA 6.2 too. There is a chance good chance that there is some IDAPython API designed specifically for that, but I was unable to find it.

This definitely works in IDA 6.8.
Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me on IDA 6.2, but +1 in case someone with a different version is trying to solve the same problem